# Need LINQ query to search a list of string in a list of input values

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose i have to search in `inputValues` list which are started with list of `codes`. I have done it with the help of `foreach` loop. But I need to did the same using **LINQ**:

```
List<string> inputValues = new List<string> {
    "S083*01999900FN0060000.000001097.00000.0020020101",
    "S013*01999900FN0060000.100001097.00000.0020020101",
    "S529*01999900FN0060000.999001097.00000.0020020101",
    "S530*01999900FN0060000.222001097.00000.0020020101",
    "S530*45199900FMo060000.222001097.00000.0020020101",
    "S541*01999900FN0060000.999001097.00000.0020020101",
    "S519*01999900FN0060000.999001097.00000.0020020101",
    "S099*01999900FN0060000.999001097.00000.0020020101",
};

List<string> codes = new List<string> { 
    "S099", "S529", "S530", "I897",
};

private static List<string> GetValidList(List<string> inputValues, 
                                         List<string> codes)
{
    List<string> result=new List<string>();
        
    foreach( string item in inputValues)
    {
        foreach(string code in codes)
        {
            if (item.StartsWith(code))
                result.Add(item);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Linq query can be like this:

```
var result = inputValues
  .Where(value => codes.Any(code => value.StartsWith(code)))
  .ToList();
```

Here we for each `value` from `inputValues` check if there's a `code` from `codes` such that `value` starts from this `code`

**Method**

```
private static List<string> GetValidList(List<string> inputValues, 
                                         List<string> codes) => inputValues
  .Where(value => codes.Any(code => value.StartsWith(code)))
  .ToList();
```

**Edit:** If we want to return *duplicates* when `codes` have *duplicates* (see Harald Coppoolse's comment) we can put `SelectMany`

```
private static List<string> GetValidList(List<string> inputValues,
                                         List<string> codes) => codes
  .SelectMany(code => inputValues.Where(value => value.StartsWith(code)))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it actually works. Could you share me some link to learn some technique to build this type of LINQ?

Comment: @Srikant Mishra: I've taught myself by answering on Stack Overflow and comparing my answers with better ones. Unlike SQL, Linq is not a popular topic for courses, boot camps...

Comment: You do realize that this answer gives a different result than the original. For example if `List<string> codes = new List<string> { "S099", "S099"};` then the original code would give you the input value `"S099*01999900FN0060000.999001097.00000.0020020101"` twice, while this answer would give it only once

Comment: @Harald Coppoolse: thank you for the interesting case (even if I *doubt* if `codes` will have duplicates)! If we want to have duplicate results when `codes` have duplicates we can use `SelectMany`. I've edited the answer